# How Can I Parse SOAP Data in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

**How Can I Parse SOAP Data in React Native? I need help pls someone help me, i tried, if i write console.log(channels[0]);
is output;
just {**

The contents of the view appear blank on the screen.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
        channels: [],
    });
}

componentDidMount() {


    axios.post('xxxx', xmls, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
            Accept: 'application/xml',
          
        },
    })
        .then((response) => {
            const channels = convert.xml2json(response.data, {alwaysArray:true,ignoreAttributes: true, compact: true, ignoreDeclaration: true, fullTagEmptyElement: true, spaces: 4 })
            this.setState({ channels: [] })
            console.log(channels);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));




}

render() {


    return (
        <View>

            {this.channels.map((v, id) => {
                <View key={id}>{v.item}</View>
            })}
       
       

        </View>
       
    )
}
```

}

Comment: You should do like this. ```this.state.channels.map((v,id)=>...```
``this.channels``is not defined.

Comment: and you set the channels as empty array. change `` this.setState({ channels: [] })`` to ``this.setState({ channels: channels })``